# I have a char for letter from a to z, i need to find on the server just with clicking the letter of the alphabet

Tags: ruby-on-rails, char

This is my index.html.erb

```
<% for char in 'A'..'Z' %>
  <a href="/pacientes?char=<%= char%>"><%= char%></a>
<% end %>
```

And this is my controller:

```
if params[:char].nil?
  @pacientes = Paciente.all
elsif
  @pacientes = Paciente.where("apellido1 = ?", @char = params[:char])
end

respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @pacientes }
end
```

What i need is when i click on the Letter A all the persons starting with letter A, at this moment i just can find them if on URL i place the full parameter of the search

Comment: <p>
 <% for char in 'A'..'Z' %>
 <a href="/pacientes?char=<%= char%>"><%= char%></a>
 
<% end %> 
</p>

Comment: Thats my index<p>
 <% for char in 'A'..'Z' %>

 <a href="/pacientes?char=<%= char%>"><%= char%></a>

 
<% end %> 

</p>

Comment: I can find what i have on the DB, but what i need is to show all the people that start with the letter i click!

Comment: Use the edit functionality, and preview before submitting. To answer your question:
Take a look at the different search gems, such as Searchlogic (see great screencast [over att railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/176-searchlogic)). Using a gem is probably the easiest way to get records starting with a certain letter.

Comment: No it's not @Kalle, a gem is not needed for this kind of simple request...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this:

```
# in the controller
if params[:char].nil?
  @pacientes = Paciente.all
elsif
  @pacientes = Paciente.where("apellido1 LIKE ?", "#{params[:char]}%")
end

respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @pacientes }
end
```

A **shorter version**:

```
# in the controller
@pacientes = Paciente.where("apellido1 LIKE ?", "#{params[:char]}%")

respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @pacientes }
end
```

With the shorter version, if params[:char] is nil, the where clause will return all the records.

Comment: You have to put `%` in your parameter: `"apellido1 LIKE ?" , "#{params[:char]}%"`. Otherwise the char will be sanitized and your query will be malformed.